# scrapy read start url from an xml file and that url has "&"

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, scrapy

First let me be clear with you,
i have a URL that has `&` in it, and I want to crawl it.

When i crawl it manually from the command line, it works perfectly, but when i tell the spider to read the start url from a `xml` file, i got problem like the xml file is not defined properly, i 100% sure that the problem is the `&` in the start url, because when i used my code to read any url that doesn't have the `&` sign in it , ti works perfectly

i tried to change the `&` to `&amp;` but that didn't work

help please

by the way, this is the url 
https://itunes.apple.com/ae/genre/ios-social-networking/id6005?mt=8&letter=A

Answer (score 1):

Try percent-encoding the ampersand:

```
https://itunes.apple.com/ae/genre/ios-social-networking/id6005?mt=8%26letter=A
```

Or, as an alternative, use `;` as a delimiter:

```
https://itunes.apple.com/ae/genre/ios-social-networking/id6005?mt=8;letter=A
```

Comment: Thanks for the answering, I will update you tomorrow, because i have to run this problem with my manager

Comment: could you help me here please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28401403/xpath-how-to-get-text-when-the-brother-is-not-an-element

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli looks like you've solved that problem already :)