# xpath how to get text when the brother is not an element

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

i used to have this form;

```
<li>
    <span>name:</span>
    <p>Seca </p>
</li>
```

and I was using this xpath to get the `seca`:

```
ul/li/span[normalize-space(text())='name:']/following-sibling::p[1]/text())
```

and everything was working good.

**Now** i don't have the `p` tag. so I just have this:

```
<li>
    <span>name:</span>
    Seca
</li>
```

what edit should I do to my code to get the `seca` now please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, "Seca" is just another child of the `li` element - and thus a following sibling of the `span` element. Using

```
//ul/li/span[normalize-space(text())='name:']/following-sibling::text()
```

gives you

```
[EMPTY LINE]
Seca
[EMPTY LINE]
```

you might want to exclude those whitespace-only lines:

```
normalize-space(//ul/li/span[normalize-space(text())='name:']/following-sibling::text())
```

and the result will be

```
Seca
```

If your actual input includes more text nodes, do not forget to add `[1]`to the expression.

---

Note that the expression could be a lot easier if there is actually no reason to normalize the text content of `span` and to only consider its immediate child text nodes:

```
//ul/li[span='name:']/text()[2]
```